Difficulty Handling Missing Information in Rvest Data Scraping
I'm currently working on a web scraping project in R using the rvest package. While the package works for extracting data from websites, I'm encountering difficulties when dealing with missing information on the web pages.
Specifically, when certain elements I'm targeting with html_node or html_text functions are not present on a page, my script breaks when binding the row to the data frame.
I've tried implementing error handling techniques like tryCatch and if statements, but I'm struggling to find an effective way to bypass missing elements and adding the existing information in a data frame.
Could someone please provide guidance or examples on how to handle missing information gracefully while scraping data with rvest? Are there any specific functions or strategies I should be using to achieve this?
Thanks in advance for any assistance!
website: https://expresso.pt/api/molecule/search?q=trotinete&page=**PAGENUMBER**&offset=0
language: R
output: CSV
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

expresso_scraper <- data.frame()

get_article <- function(link_article) {
  tryCatch({
    article_page <- read_html(link_article)
    print(link_article)
    
    article_text <- article_page %>% html_nodes("#article-body-1 span") %>% html_text() %>% paste()
    Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause for 2 seconds
    return(article_text)
  }, error = function(e) {
    message("Error occurred while scraping article: ", link_article)
    return(NA)
  })
  
}

search_term <- "trotinete"

#set_cookies()

for(page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 2)) {
  link <- paste0("https://expresso.pt/api/molecule/search?q=", search_term, "&page=", page_result, "&offset=0")     
  print(link)
  Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause for 2 seconds
  page <- read_html(link)
  
  if (grepl("href", page)) {
    title <- page %>% html_nodes(".title a") %>% html_text()
    link_article <- page %>% html_nodes(".title a") %>% html_attr("href") %>%
      ifelse(!grepl("\\.pt", .), paste("https://expresso.pt", ., sep = ""), .)
    date <- page %>% html_nodes(".timeStamp") %>%  html_attr("datetime") 
    section <- page %>% html_nodes(".mainSection") %>% html_text() %>% ifelse(length(.) == 0, NA, .)
    summary <- page %>% html_nodes(".lead") %>% html_text() %>% ifelse(length(.) == 0, NA, .)
    author <- page %>% html_nodes(".author") %>% html_text() %>% ifelse(length(.) == 0, NA, .)
    complete_article <- sapply(link_article, FUN = get_article, USE.NAMES = FALSE) 
    complete_article <- sapply(complete_article, paste, collapse = "\n") # Flattening the list
    expresso_scraper <- rbind(expresso_scraper, data.frame(title, link_article, date, section, author, summary, complete_article, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) 
  }
}

author
write.csv2(expresso_scraper, "expresso.csv")


There is no standardized approach. You managed it quite well, while running it returns proper data.frame with 20 elements (as it should). There might be better functions to handle empty strings like this is.empty() but you can create own depending on returned data type / needs.

Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will try to use the isEmpty() function and see if it works. The issue I find is that the data isn't reliable, as the final CSV will copy the same information into different cells.

Try to replace NA with "" empty string if that's helps with .csv

Once again, thank you for your feedback. I attempted your approach, but it appears that after the 'date' field (which is always present), the results are simply duplicated across all cells for each page of results. Image of the CSV.

I personally would just loop though list elements and parse those separately, i.e. instead of building vectors for frame columns, let's collect items for frame rows into a named lists. This way, there's no need to check for missing elements or worry about matching vector lengths, if rvest does not find requested element in that specific <li> element, value for that row is just set to NA.
Some links are behind a paywall, so I'm not really sure what's happening there, but I would assume complete article retrieval would need a somewhat different approach depending on the site, that's why get_article() first decides which parser to call.
slow_*() functions are rate-limited, purrr::slowly() makes it quite convenient to limit request rates in pipelines and mutate calls.
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

# request and parse search results
search_results <- function(search_term, page){
  read_html(str_glue("https://expresso.pt/api/molecule/search?q={search_term}&page={page}&offset=0")) |>
    html_elements("ul.listArticles > li") |>
    map(\(li) list(
      title        = html_element(li, ".title a") |> html_text(trim = TRUE),
      link_article = html_element(li, ".title a") |> html_attr("href"),
      date         = html_element(li, ".timeStamp") |> html_attr("datetime"),
      section      = html_element(li, ".mainSection") |> html_text(trim = TRUE),
      summary      = html_element(li, ".lead") |> html_text(trim = TRUE),
      author       = html_element(li, ".author") |> html_text(trim = TRUE)
    ))
}

# rate-limited search_results
slow_search <- slowly(search_results, rate = rate_delay(2))

# site-specific article parser
get_expresso <- function(link_article){
  read_html(link_article) |>
    html_elements("#article-body-1 > div > *") |>
    html_text(trim = TRUE) |> 
    str_c(collapse = "\n")
}

# rate-limited article parser
slow_expresso <- slowly(get_expresso, rate = rate_delay(2))

# use url to select & call apropriate site-specific parser
get_article <- function(link_article) {
  if (str_starts(link_article, "https://expresso.pt/")){
    return(slow_expresso(link_article))
  }else if(str_starts(link_article, "something else")){
    return("call some other site-specific parser")
  }else{
    return(NA)
  }
}

Main loop:
search_term <- "trotinete"
pages <- 1:2

expresso_scraper <- 
  pages |>
  # 1st map() returns a list of named lists
  map(\(page) slow_search(search_term, page), .progress = TRUE) |>
  # 2nd map() returns a list of data.frames / tibbles, one per page (2)
  map(bind_rows) |>
  # combine tibbles and also store origin page number
  list_rbind(names_to = "page") |>
  # instead of ifelse, let's just use str_replace on relative URLs that start with `/`
  mutate(link_article = str_replace(link_article, "^/",  "https://expresso.pt/")) |>
  # limit the number of articles to 5 in this example
  head(5) |>
  # get complete articles
  mutate(complete_article = map_chr(link_article, get_article, .progress = TRUE))

  
expresso_scraper
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#>    page title         link_article date  section summary author complete_article
#>   <int> <chr>         <chr>        <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>           
#> 1     1 Líderes na t… https://exp… 2023… Lídere… Mudanç… Franc… "1. Fiscalidade…
#> 2     1 Líderes na t… https://lei… 2023… Jornal… Mudanç… <NA>    <NA>           
#> 3     1 Neste hotel … https://exp… 2023… 20 Ano… Respir… BCBM   "Abriu em 2017 …
#> 4     1 “Cinto-me vi… https://exp… 2023… Socied… De aco… Lusa   "A campanha de …
#> 5     1 Condicioname… https://exp… 2023… Socied… As res… Lusa   "Os condicionam…

Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0

My approach to go through pages is to base on <li> elements and loop through it. I also moved collapsing article_text to get_article() function and add few white space trims.
library(rvest)

expresso_scraper <- data.frame(
  title = character(),
  link_article = character(),
  date = as.Date(character()),
  section = character(),
  author = character(),
  summary = character(),
  complete_article = character()
)

get_article <- function(link_article) {
  tryCatch({
    article_page <- read_html(link_article)
    print(link_article)
    
    article_text <- 
      article_page |>
      html_nodes("#article-body-1 span") |>
      html_text() |>
      paste()
    article_text <- paste(article_text, collapse = "\n")
    Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause for 2 seconds
    return(article_text)
  }, error = function(e) {
      message("Error occurred while scraping article: ", link_article)
      return(NA)
  })

}

search_term <- "trotinete"


for(page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 2)) {
  link <- paste0("https://expresso.pt/api/molecule/search?q=", search_term, "&page=", page_result, "&offset=0")     
  print(link)
  Sys.sleep(2)  # Pause for 2 seconds
  page <- read_html(link)
  
  lists <- page |>
    html_nodes(".entry_HT-default")
  
  for (aa in seq_along(lists)) {
    print(paste(page_result, ":::", aa))
  
  title <- lists[[aa]] |> 
    html_nodes(".title a") |>
    html_text() |>
    trimws()

  link_article <- lists[[aa]] |>
    html_nodes(".title a") |>
    html_attr("href")
    
  if(!grepl("\\.pt", link_article)) {
    link_article <- paste0("https://expresso.pt", link_article)
  }
  
  date <- lists[[aa]] |>
    html_node(".timeStamp") |>
    html_attr("datetime") |>
    as.Date()

  section <- lists[[aa]] |>
    html_node(".mainSection") |> 
    html_text() |>
    trimws()
  
  summary <- lists[[aa]] |>
    html_node(".lead") |>
    html_text() |>
    trimws()
  
  author <- lists[[aa]] |>
    html_node(".author") |>
    html_text() |>
    trimws() |>
    stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = "(\\s)+(,)(\\s)+", replacement = ", ")

  complete_article <- sapply(link_article, FUN = get_article, USE.NAMES = FALSE) |>
    trimws()
  
  expresso_scraper <- rbind(expresso_scraper, 
    data.frame(title, link_article, date, section, author, summary, complete_article)) 
  }
}

write.csv2(expresso_scraper, "/home/sapi/expresso.csv", row.names = FALSE)


Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0
EDIT: a similar approach as margusl's above, I like his map() and purrr::slowly() usage :)
